# Making old chime work with Ring doorbell

Tags: electrical

I have an old (already installed) electrical chime.
When I was installing a new ring video doorbell I remember adding a jumper in the old chime.

However I want the old chime to also ring when someone presses the ring doorbell (not just the notification on my phone).

Can I remove the jumper and the old chime will just work or cause any electrical issues?

Comment: Jumper ? what jumper, where ? on the transformer ?

Comment: Yes, there was a small cable provided with the ring doorbell and had the instruction in the manual to put it in the doorbell chime transformer.

Comment: @Ayusman perhaps you meant "doorbell chime" rather than "doorbell chime transformer". Some of the Ring doorbells require that jumper to bypass certain existing chimes. Depends on the Ring doorbell model, VA rating of your doorbell transformer, and your existing chime's design.

Answer (score 0):

Your only limit is probably the transformer capacity.

If it is >50VA it should be fine.

Anything less it will not be able to supply juice to both.

Best to check the label on the transformer.